# All values of constant $a$ such that $f(z) = \frac{z^2 - z +1}{z(z-1)^2}+\frac{a}{\sin z}$ has an antiderivative in given domain

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to find all the possible $a \in \mathbb{C}$ for which the following function has an antiderivative in the domain $U = \{z : |z|<2\} \setminus \{0,1\}$
$$f(z) = \frac{z^2 - z +1}{z(z-1)^2}+\frac{a}{\sin z} = \frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}+\frac{a}{\sin z}$$
Now, it's clear that in the domain $U,\ (z-1)^{-2} \ $ will have an antiderivative. So we're only bothered about $g(z) = f(z) - (z-1)^{-2}$

We would want the following

$$\int_{\gamma}g(z)dz = 0$$
where $\gamma$ is a closed path in $V = \{z : |z|<2\}$ with $0,\ 1$ in it's interior; and by Residue Theorem we get
$$2 \pi i + a \cdot 2 \pi i \cdot 1=0 \implies a = -1$$

Is this reasoning correct?

Now, I have the following question: What does the antiderivate of $g$ look like? Since we have the problematic $1/z$ term. Are we talking about something of the form

$$G(z) =\int_{z_0}^{z} \left(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{\sin z}\right) dz$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes. To be more precise, define$$\begin{array}{rccc}\varphi\colon&D(0,2)\setminus\{0\}&\longrightarrow&\mathbb C\\&z&\mapsto&\begin{cases}\dfrac1z-\dfrac1{\sin z}&\text{ if }z\neq0\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then you can define, for each $z\in D(0,2)$, $G(z)$ as$$G(z)=\int_{[0,z]}\varphi(z)\,\mathrm dz,$$where $[0,z]$ is the path$$\begin{array}{ccc}[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb C\\t&\mapsto&tz\end{array}$$and $G$ will be an antiderivative of your function. Actually, any other path in $D(0,2)$ going from $0$ to $z$ will do.